# select currently focused contenteditable div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi i would like to select the parent div of currently placed cursor in a contenteditable div.

the process is, there are multiple contenteditable div in a page. i'd like to select the div which the caret/ cursor is currently positioned. so that using jquery i could change the css.

following is my html code of the div:

```
     <button id="changer">change color</button>
     <div id="container">
          <div class="section" contenteditable="true">
          <p>this is my editable paragraph</p>
      </div>

      <div class="section" contenteditable="true">
         <p>this is my editable paragraph 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

following is my jquery code so far:-

```
        $('#changer').click(function(){
             document.activeElement.css({'background':'black'}); 
        });
```

but this gives me the error :- `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

edit:-

the process is when the user clicks a button a color palette lightbox will appear. on click of any of the color on the color palette. the jquery is going to select the currently focused contenteditable div. and change the css.
i want to know how to select the currently focused contenteditable div using jquery.

Comment: You want to select it on user interraction or what? It is not clear what you are expecting

Comment: i mean i want to select the currently focused contenteditable div

Comment: So just bind onfocus event and inside handler use `this`

Comment: wait let me edit the question.

Comment: But then is the button descendant of the DIV? If not, by clicking the button, the DIV will lost focus. Improve your question by posting all relevant code in question

Comment: ok sure wait i will add my jquery code so far

Comment: hi i have edited my question please check

Comment: `document.activeElement` is a native DOM element, it's not a jQuery object and doesn't have `css` method. Though fixing this won't help, the clicked button will be the active element at the time. You'd need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hxk8cxgf/).

Comment: `document.activeElement` is a native element, it has no `.css()` method, so it trigger that error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the code below console logs the text inside the contenteditable div which is focused. if you write `$(this)` inside the event handler it will reference the currently `div` focused

```
$('[contenteditable="true"]').focus(function(){
  console.log($(this).text()); // for example, do whatever you please here
  // you said you want to find the parent div of the element focused
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  // now $parent is a reference of the parent div of the focused element
});
```

The tricky thing is that when the user clicks the button, the contenteditable is not focused anymore. so let's make a variable where we store our last `focused contenteditable div` , and when the user clicks a button, the changes will be made on that very variable.

like so :

```
var lastFocused;

$('[contenteditable="true"]').focus(function(){
  lastFocused = $(this);
});

$('#changer').on('click', function(){
  console.log(lastFocused);
  lastFocused.css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

see codepen : [here](http://codepen.io/CerrahogluAli/pen/KwvOJj)

Comment: hi could you read the question again, please i have made some edits.

Comment: updated the answer, you can see an example on my codepen too !

Answer (score 3):

So I think what you are trapped is how to get the `div[contenteditable]` which was focused.

The idea is to store the item when it was trigger by a `focus` event.

```
$(function() {
    var $focus_item = null;
    $('[contenteditable]').focus(function() {
        $focus_item = $(this);
    });
    $('#changer').click(function(){
         $focus_item.css({'background':'black'}); 
    });
});
```

Comment: i can you please read the question again? i have made some changes